# Exposing polymorphism with boost python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

i am starting to get really frustrated trying to expose a simple C++ polymorphism to python with boost::python.

I do have the following structure in C++:

```
struct Base {
    int typeID;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    int derivedProperty;
}

//and some more from base derived types....    

Base *returnSomethingDerivedFromBase(...) {
    Derived *ret = new Derived;
    ret->derivedProperty = 1234;
    return ret;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo) 
{
    class_<Base>("Base")
        .add_property("baseProperty", &Base::baseProperty);

    class_<Derived, bases<Base> >("Derived")
        .add_property("derivedProperty", &Derived::derivedProperty);

    def("returnSomethingDerivedFromBase", returnSomethingDerivedFromBase);    
}
```

And in Python i just want to have the following:

```
object = returnSomethingFromDerived() #object is of type Base
if object.typeID = 1:
    #here i want to cast to Derived and access "derivedProperty"
    #but this is not working :-( :
    object.__class__ = Derived
```

Is there a way to accomplish this at all? Or isn´t this possible as it would be in C++ ?

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i missed the virtual destructor in the Base class. So here is how it works:

```
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
    int typeID;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    int derivedProperty;
}

//and some more from base derived types....    

Base *returnSomethingDerivedFromBase(...) {
    Derived *ret = new Derived;
    ret->derivedProperty = 1234;
    return ret;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo) 
{
    class_<Base>("Base")
        .add_property("baseProperty", &Base::baseProperty);

    class_<Derived, bases<Base> >("Derived")
        .add_property("derivedProperty", &Derived::derivedProperty);

    def("returnSomethingDerivedFromBase", returnSomethingDerivedFromBase, return_value_policy<manage_new_object>());    
}
```

But now i have a different problem. When i try to return this type in a tuple i again lose the type info:

```
tuple returnSomethingDerivedFromBase(...) {
    Derived *ret = new Derived;
    ret->derivedProperty = 1234;
    return make_tuple(ret);
}
```

Comment: If you create a separate question for your new problem, I would be glad to post a thorough solution.  However, in short, the tuple needs to be constructed with a `boost::python::object` in which ownership of the `Derived` instance has been transferred to Python.